# For a given transmitter mains wattage, is its TPO wattage affected by the transmission frequency?

Tags: efficiency

Using a 1000 watt (mains, not TPO) transmitter capable of theoretically transmitting on any frequency, would TPO change based on frequency at which we transmit (LF, MF, HF, VHF, UHF,...)?

I mean, is it more expensive in terms of wasted power to transmit on a certain side of the RF spectrum rather than on the other, with the same mains power? And why?

If TPO remains constant, would ERP remain unchanged too at any frequencies, assuming in all cases that no power is reflected back into the transmitter from the antenna, and a neutral antenna gain?

Answer (score 3):

The first part of your question seems to be about transmitter efficiency.  Engineers designing transmitters must make many design compromises at any frequency.  At frequencies of several gigahertz amplifier and oscillator efficiency drops tremendously, and producing even a 10-Watt signal can be a real achievement.  Speaking very roughly, losses increase as frequency increases.

The second part of your question is about transmission line and antenna losses.  For open wire line and coaxial cable losses increase with frequency, but at microwave frequencies waveguides become practical, and waveguides can be very efficient.  Again speaking very generally, losses tend to increase as frequency increases.  Of course as the frequency gets lower, the antenna must be larger and higher, and generally more expensive, in order to be efficient.

Your question focuses on one factor, power efficiency, but in the real world the designer of a radio system must also be concerned with many other factors: the expense, the size of the equipment, the size of the antenna, the path loss (the loss between the transmitting antenna and the receiving antenna), the noise present in the band that must be overcome in order for the receiver to hear, and so on.  It's difficult to make blanket statements about one part of the radio spectrum being better than other parts without more specifics about the problem.  If the goal is to talk to submerged submarines, then the answer can be a very large antenna and a powerful transmitter at a very low frequency.  If the goal is to inexpensively allow two hikers a mile apart to communicate, then the answer can be a pair of FRS handheld radios.

Answer (score 0):

rclocher3 is correct when it comes to increasing losses as F goes up and lower practical antenna efficiency as F goes down. There is probably a very broad optimum which would be somewhere between 80m and 2m depending on where you live. The method of modulation is also a big factor. For example old analog FM and its digital cousins FSK and PSK don't need a linear amplifier and therefore run in more efficient classes like C or D or E. A class C VHF PA will be more efficient than a class AB HF linear SSB. Full carrier AM can run a class D modulator and a class E final giving mains efficiencies of over 90%. Looking at things this way makes AM not so bad.